# unable to get key value

Tags: javascript, node.js

There was a problem when working with Spotify API, trying to get the value of the key of the duration of the track being played, but as a result “undefined”.  I get it like this:

```
const data = await spotifyApi.getMyCurrentPlaybackState(userID);

console.log(data.body.duration_ms);
```

If you try to output Body yourself, then it has this key in it, and it has the value of the length of the track in milliseconds

```
console.log(data.body)
```

Comment: Can you provide the output from data.body please

Comment: https://prnt.sc/22rbpni

Comment: @user1010101010101010 is this the result of the `console.log(data.body)`?

Comment: if that is the output It seems like you have to use `data.body.item.duration_ms`

Comment: omg, i'm sorry. is this a true... (data.body.item.duration_ms)

Answer (score 1):

You are inside the item key ;)
You want body.duration_ms

[image]